# FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/root/analytics/venv-nerapi/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload' while creating virtual environment

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualenv, python-3.6

```
$virtualenv -p python3.6m  ../venv-nerapi
```

Above command gives following error.

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python3.6m
Using base prefix '/usr/local'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 352, in copyfile
    os.symlink(srcpath, dest)
FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload' -> '/root/analytics/venv-nerapi/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2343, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 712, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 927, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1132, in install_python
    copyfile(join(stdlib_dir, fn), join(lib_dir, fn), symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 355, in copyfile
    copyfileordir(src, dest, symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 330, in copyfileordir
    shutil.copytree(src, dest, symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 315, in copytree
    os.makedirs(dst)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 220, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/root/analytics/venv-nerapi/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload'
```

I followed following [Github](https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/issues/3183) issue thread but din't find any luck.
Could any body tell whats went wrong ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that there was existing `venv-nerapi` . Deleting existing virtual env and re-creating it worked fine.